# Link to a react Component in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, activeadmin

I want to link a react component to link_to rails tag. Is it possible ?

```
index do
column :uid
column :name
column :email
column :mobile
column :updated_at
column :task_details do
  link_to('tasks', react_component("users/UserTask")  )
end
actions
```

end

in the task_details link_to is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to link to rails routes from javascript [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes) might be what you want.

The other way round, so from a plain html view to a React component, is a bit more diverse, because you could set up multiple classic rails views with classic rails routes that have webpacker style react, as well as you could make use of react router within these.

But rails `link_to` won't know anything about routes defined within react router of course.